# No Default constructor to run functions in c++?

Tags: c++

i want to run the function Run in the main, but am not allowed to create object due to no default constructor. when i try to create the default constructor, i receive the message, 'Error"Game::Game int maxComponents)" provides no initialiser for:'

```
//Game.h 
#pragma once
#include "GameComponent.h"
#include <time.h>
class Game
{
private:
    int componentCount;
    GameComponent** components;
    const int TICKS_1000MS;
public:

    Game(){}    //this does not work either
    Game(int maxComponents){}   //this does not work as my default constructor
    ~Game();
    void Add(GameComponent*);
    void Run();

};

//Game.cpp
#pragma once
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;


void Game::Add(GameComponent*)
{
    components= new GameComponent*[componentCount];


}
void Game::Run()
{

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );      
    //cout << timeinfo->tm_hour<< ":" << timeinfo->tm_min << ":" << timeinfo->tm_sec << endl;

    for(int n=0;n<componentCount;n++)
    {
        components[n]->Update(timeinfo);

    }
}


Game::~Game()
{
}


//main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Game obj1;
    obj1.Run();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, how do i create a default constructor here? i've tried to use member initialising too, doesn't work. and copy constructor.

Comment: Your code is far from the least possible required to demonstrate the problem.  When posting such a problem, remove everything you don't think is involved in causing the problem, until you have an example which you think should compile, and has everything it needs to compile, and nothing else.  As an example, the variable `componentCount` -- do you think it is involved in your problem?  If not, remove it and confirm you still have your problem.  Do the same for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A default constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments.  So, you should declare a constructor that looks something like this:

```
Game() { }
```

You can keep your other constructor - normal function overloading applies to constructors, so it will use your Game(int) constructor when you specify a single integer argument, and Game() when you specify no arguments.

However, in your case `Game` contains a `const int` member (`TICKS_1000MS`).  Since it's `const`, it's expected to be initialized in the constructor.  So you should do something like this:

```
Game() : TICKS_1000MS(123) { } // replace 123 with whatever the value should be
```

You need to do that for all constructors.

It's a little silly to have a non-static const member of a class which is always initialized to the same value (as opposed to a value passed in as an argument to the constructor). Consider making it an enum instead:

```
enum { TICKS_1000MS = 123 };
```

or, a `static const` member:

```
static const int TICKS_1000MS;
```

and initialize it in `Game.cpp`:

```
const int Game::TICKS_1000MS = 123;
```

Comment: What's the full error message you're getting?  I think it may have been cut off in your question.

Comment: I think I guessed what the real problem is - see my updated answer.

Comment: No, actually that is all i get - 'Error"Game::Game (int maxComponents)" provides no initialiser for:'

Comment: So, if you need to initialize `TICKS_1000MS` in your default constructor, what do you need to do in yet another constructor?

Comment: Yakk - same thing: `Game(int maxComponents) : TICKS_1000MS(123) { }`

Comment: So, when this happens, do you get "provides no initializer for:" errors?  If you do, copy the entire error, and paste it here in backticks (the character under the ~ to the left of the number 1, aka `)

Comment: i don't get "provides no initializer for:" errors" with the Game constructor or the enum/static - (they work fine), but i can not run the functions in main.cpp with the enum/static by initialising in game.cpp file. With the Game constuctor, this allows for it to work, so I will just use the first one.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have defined a constructor other than than the default one, the default constructor is not provided anymore so you have to define it manually:

```
public:
    Game() {}
    Game(int maxComponents){}
```

Now you have a default constructor and an overloaded constructor which takes 1 integer parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the default parameterless constructor. When you define a constructor you no longer get the default that would have been created behind the scenes.

```
Game(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is the one that does not take any parameters, in your case `Game(){}`.

You do not seem to use the constructor parameter, but if you do, you will have to provide a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can so something along these lines, you class Game needs to initialize const int in both the constructors:

```
class Game
{
private:
    int componentCount;
    GameComponent** components;
    const int TICKS_1000MS;
public:

    Game(): TICKS_1000MS(100)
    {}    //this does not work either
    Game(int maxComponents): TICKS_1000MS(100)
    {}   //this does not work as my default constructor
    ~Game();
    void Add(GameComponent*);
    void Run();

};
```

As pointed out by others you need to intialize const data in ctor or initializer list.